# contacts not displaying

Tags: contacts, bugs

Out of the blue, I looked at my messages and noticed that the contacta were not displaying. Only phone numbers.
I then tried to access my contacts and my phone icons but it would freeze up for a few seconds and only display a black screen.
I don't want to do a factory reset. Can anyone help?

Comment: I assume you've tried the basics? Turn off/on, remove battery. And how long has this been happening?

Comment: Are your contacts in your Google account or on your Phone/SIM?

Comment: My girlfriend and I both started having this same problem with our Samsung Charge's on Verizon. I don't think I've seen anything freezing up though, although the phone does seem less stable than it used to be

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Handcent SMS ... http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44624/handcent-has-forgotten-half-of-my-contacts