# Handcent has forgotten half of my contacts

Tags: contacts, handcent-sms

So I've noticed recently that some of my friends contact info has disappeared, at least when using Handcent.  If I get a text from them, I only see their numbers, and if I try and send a message they aren't listed in my contacts. If I use the default Text Messaging tool all of my contacts are there, and if I send a message to someone from there, I'll see it in Handcent as well, but without the contact info.

I have A Droid RAZR, running Andoird 4.1.2

Comment: I use Handcent too, and I noticed sometimes this happens if I use my phone's "Free Memory" tool. Usually, after starting HS then closing it with the back button, then going back in fixes it for me

Comment: *How to shoot yourself in the foot using... task killers?* Sorry, but I couldn't resist :) @Luke is that "Free Memory" tool a kind of task killer, and was even pre-installed? It's a known thing that task-killers might cause more trouble than they are solving, when not used carefully. It's not their purpose to "free memory", for example :)

Comment: @Izzy It came built in to the phone, it's a widget from LG that closes background apps for me. I know the behaviour it causes on my phone, and I like it, personally

Comment: OK with me -- I just wanted to point out :)